# Access class from helper in controller Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I created an helper and I try to use it in one of my controllers,but I got an error, and I am not sure why.

```
//StringHelper.php
namespace App\Helpers;

class StringHelper
{
    public function example($str1){
        //CODE
    }
}


//config/app.php
'aliases' => [
    'StringHelper' => App\Helpers\StringHelper::class,
]


//In controller 
use StringHelper;

$percentage = StringHelper::example($title);
```

> Non-static method App\Helpers\StringHelper::example() should not be
>   called statically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the method `example($str1)` is not static, you need to call it by instance.

I think you are calling other instance's methods in `example`, so the simple way is call the method by instance.

```php
$helper = new StringHelper();
$percentage = $helper->example($title);
```

Or you need to defined all those methods to static.

Comment: I also change 'use', with use App\Helpers\StringHelper, and it work, thank you!